# Architecture for Entity framework & WCF

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, soa

What architecture i should follow in order to use entity framework & WCF? It would be nice if there is a link available

Comment: This is way too broad to ask..... you need to be more specific. What apps do you want to create? EF and WCF are two totally separate technologies - you can use one without the other.

Comment: Or you can use WCF Data Services. But it depends on what you want to do. This is not a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical three layer architecture contain a UI layer, a logic layer and a data (access) layer. So is you are talking about EF and WCF, you are talking about the data and logic layer or the data access layer exclusively.

If you are going to expose your physical datamodel using EF and WCF data services, you are actually exposing your datamodel one-to-one in the OData protocol. Used that way, I would call that my **Data access service**.

If you are going to use EF to map your physical datamodel into a logical datamodel using EF and then allow operations to be performed on that after validation and business logic have run in a WCF service with a formalized interface, I would call that a combination of a **Data layer and a logic layer**. EF does the coupling between the layers and WCF exposes the capabilities.